# Why Groovy's Map scales better than Array?

Tags: java, arrays, groovy, hashmap

I came into this problemn today and I could not figure out why groovy array is not scaling better than Map when it gets bigger.

In my example I create an Map (LinkedHashMap) and an String array (String[]). Then I iterate from 0 to 10^7 inserting i into the Map or Array. I do it 10 times to be sure that outliers don't mess the results.

```
int max = 10**7
int numTests = 10

long totalTimeMap = 0
long totalTimeArray = 0

numTests.times{
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis()

    Map m = [:]
    max.times {
        m[it] = "${it}"
    }

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis()
    totalTimeMap += (end-start)
}

numTests.times {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis()

    String[] s = new String[max]
    max.times{
        s[it] = "${it}"
    }

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis()
    totalTimeArray += (end-start)
}

println "Map: ${totalTimeMap}"
println "Array: ${totalTimeArray}"
```

The output was unexpected since the Map had a better performance then Array:

```
Map: 49361
Array: 101123
```

I made the same experiment in java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int max = 10000000;
        int numTests = 10;

        long totalTimeMap = 0;
        long totalTimeArray = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<numTests; i++){
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            Map m = new LinkedHashMap();
            for(int j=0; j<max; j++){
                m.put(j, "" + j);
            }

            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            totalTimeMap += (end-start);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<numTests; i++){
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            String[] s = new String[max];
            for(int j=0; j<max; j++){
                s[j] = "" + j;
            }

            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            totalTimeArray += (end-start);
        }

        System.out.println("Map: " + totalTimeMap);
        System.out.println("Array: " + totalTimeArray);
    }
```

and the output was expected (Array faster than Map):

```
Map: 34564
Array: 12822
```

My question is: why the Map is faster than the Array when using Groovy?

Comment: And this is consistent across multiple executions? Just being pedantic.

Comment: yes it is. You can set max to 10^6 or 10^5 so the example runs faster.

Comment: Also make sure it's actually an array; Groovy `[]` normally creates a list, an `ArrayList`, which will have resizing penalties.

Comment: Your profiling is flawed. The second test may have benefited from the first one warming up the cache. Each test need to run in its own JVM instance.

Comment: Also you should test total time instead of summing incremental times

Comment: @DaveNewton if I println s.getClass() I get a class [Ljava.lang.String;

Comment: @SteveKuo, I tried your sugestion but Array is still slower than Map

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you are adding the String to the array in Groovy, you're creating a templated String, which is then getting converted back to a java string (after the templating is done) as it has to fit in a `String[]`

For the `Map` version, you're just storing a templated string, so no evaluation has to be done...

The following benchmarking code:

```
@Grab('org.gperfutils:gbench:0.4.3-groovy-2.4')

int max = 10000

new groovyx.gbench.BenchmarkBuilder().run {
    'Array' {
        String[] s = new String[max]
        max.times { int idx ->
            s[idx] = Integer.toString(idx)
        }  
    }
    'List' {
        def s = []
        max.times{
            s << "${it}"
        }  
    }
    'Map' {
        Map m = [:]
        max.times {
            m[it] = "${it}"
        }
    }
}.prettyPrint()
```

Where we don't use GroovyStrings in the Array method, gives me the result:

```
* Groovy: 2.4.3
* JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02, Oracle Corporation)
    * JRE: 1.8.0_45
    * Total Memory: 800.5 MB
    * Maximum Memory: 1820.5 MB
* OS: Mac OS X (10.10.3, x86_64)

Options
=======
* Warm Up: Auto (- 60 sec)
* CPU Time Measurement: On

          user  system      cpu     real

Array  1819502    6491  1825993  1833209
List   1697948    6533  1704481  1724448
Map    2040521    8932  2049453  2116760
```

Comment: Bravo! Map: 38225 Array: 34171. Thanks!

Comment: Lol, both are awesome, one for profiling, the other for breakfast ;-)